# How to set default value to <select> in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two selects one for classes and another for teachers as follows,

```
    <label for="">Select Class</label><br> 
    <select ng-model="currentClass" ng-options="class as class.name for class in classes" ng-change="listTeachers()">
    <option value="">Select Class</option>
</select>  


    <label for="">Select Teacher</label><br> 
        <select ng-model="currentTeacher" ng-options="teacher as teacher.name for teacher in teachers" ng-change="showStudents()">
        <option value="">Select Teacher</option>
    </select>
```

1. My problem is, if choose class and then choose teacher it's fine, but after choosing teacher if again I choose another class then I want to set 2nd select a value as "select teacher", how to do it?
2. Also tell me, is there any way of setting default value instead of setting it through **option tag**?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

in your `controller` on the `listTeachers()` function you need
to set the model on the value you desire, example:

```
vm.listTeachers = function() {
    vm.currentTeacher = '';
    ... // rest of your code 
}
```

so when ever you change your class it invokes listTeacher, and i will reset the value, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have one more question that if i put a string like vm.currentTeacher =  'select teacher', still it shows empty. i want prompted text there. how to do it?

Comment: the value in vm.currentTeacher must be the same that you want to display for your default, your option value ="" so your model to need to binding to that value, thats why in the example currentTeacher is == to ' '